# verification email with accounts-google,accounts-facebook

Tags: meteor, verification, google-account

I have the running app which sends verification emails in case of email/account name creation but it does not send verification email if I login with google/facebook; it is probably due to email address which is in services.google.email; how can I set field 'to' in Accounts.emailTemplates if it does exist.

```
configureAccounts = function() {
    setMailVerification(enableMailVerification);
};

setMailVerification = function() {
    Accounts.emailTemplates.from = 'myEmail@.com';
    Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail = {
        subject : function(user) {
            return "Confirmation"
        },
        text : function(user, url) {
            var greeting = (user.profile && user.profile.nick) ? ("Hello " + user.profile.nick + ",") : "Hello,";
            return greeting + 
                "\n\n"  + "Thank you for registration."+
                "\n"    + "To confirm click the following link:" + url +
                "\n\n"  + "thank you."
        }
    };

    Accounts.config({
        sendVerificationEmail : true,
        forbidClientAccountCreation : false
    });
};
```

please let me know if you where I should put ...services.google.email in case of google login and the same for facebook...

in other words how I can sent verification email to Meteor.user().services.google.email .. (even recalling sendUserVerificationEmail with that email does not work as it is not in 'emails')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified .email property onCreateUser as follows:

```
if(user.services != undefined) {
    console.log('services in onCreateUser');
    user.sentVerificationEmail = false;
    user.emails =[];

    var emailServices = user.services.google != undefined ?
        user.services.google.email :
        user.services.facebook.email;
    user.emails.push({
        address : emailServices,
        verified : false
    });
}

if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;

return user;
```

I called then Accounts.sentVerificationEmail then onLogin .. and it worked;

thank you all for having a look